# Pytube library, getting error in video.description

Tags: python, youtube, video-streaming, pytube

```
from pytube import YouTube

video = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDKSwtKhteE')
print('Author: ' + video.author)
print('Title: ' + video.title)
print('Description: ' + video.description)
```

Hello!

I'm trying to get a video description from a Youtube video using Pytube library in Python.

When I try to get the description I get this error

```
print('Description: ' + video.description)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

Pytube is giving me a 'None' but, why?

Any thoughts?

Thank you.

This script was working a year ago, now I have Pytube v15. I read the Pytube documentation but nothing new I found on it https://pytube.io/en/latest/api.html#pytube.YouTube.description

Comment: Do you know that this video *has* a description?

Comment: @ScottHunter It has one, but there's a bug that makes the library unable to show it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as stated in [this](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1626) issue of PyTube, there is a bug in PyTube that makes it unable to show descriptions. The only way is to write another function that fetches the description. Per [this comment](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1626#issuecomment-1742207755), the function can be implemented like this:

```py
from json import loads
from pytube import YouTube

def get_description(video: YouTube) -> str:
    i: int = video.watch_html.find('"shortDescription":"')
    desc: str = '"'
    i += 20  # excluding the `"shortDescription":"`
    while True:
        letter = video.watch_html[i]
        desc += letter  # letter can be added in any case
        i += 1
        if letter == '\\':
            desc += video.watch_html[i]
            i += 1
        elif letter == '"':
            break
    return loads(desc)
```

Putting it together:

```py
from pytube import YouTube
from json import loads

def get_description(video: YouTube) -> str:
    i: int = video.watch_html.find('"shortDescription":"')
    desc: str = '"'
    i += 20  # excluding the `"shortDescription":"`
    while True:
        letter = video.watch_html[i]
        desc += letter  # letter can be added in any case
        i += 1
        if letter == '\\':
            desc += video.watch_html[i]
            i += 1
        elif letter == '"':
            break
    return loads(desc)

video = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDKSwtKhteE')
print('Author: ' + video.author)
print('Title: ' + video.title)
print('Description: ' + get_description(video))  # HERE!
```